# Ignoring fast changes on a Boolean variable with RxSwift

Tags: boolean, rx-swift, ripple

I have a boolean Variable which is switching true/false. I need to ignore any changes which settles less than 1 second. In other words, I need just values which stays more than 1 second. How to get such output from RxSwift?

Sample1: If value is true, and changes to false and then after 0.5 seconds become true again, I need my output sequence to show nothing.

Sample2: Above scenario with 1.2 seconds lag between false and true, makes a false event in my output sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `skip`, `debounce` and `distinctUntilChanged` to achieve that:

```
aSwitch.rx.isOn
    .skip(1) // 1
    .debounce(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) // 2
    .distinctUntilChanged() // 3
    .subscribe(onNext: { isOn in
        print("IS ON: \(isOn)")
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

A little explanation:

// 1: This prevents the Switch from emitting its initial value. You can remove this if you need the initial value of the `UISwitch`

// 2: This waits until the `UISwitch` has not changed its value for at least 1 second before emitting the new value

// 3: This filters out values that have not changed. So no value is emitted if after one second of inactivity the value of the switch is the same as before the user started changing the value.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!